# Django Contactme TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I am getting a TemplateSyntaxError, that is only happening on my dev server, but works fine on the django testing server locally.

Here's my all code: https://github.com/halitalptekin/HDBlog

This error code:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /iletisim/
Could not parse the remainder: '-post-contact-form' from 'contactme-post-contact-form'
```

In template /home/templates/hdbootstrap/django_contactme/form.html, error at line 41

Here's line 41

```
<form id="CF" action="{% url contactme-post-contact-form %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? The url syntax is different in 1.4 vs. 1.5dev (master). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/internals/deprecation/#id3

Comment: Just change the hyphens to underscores in your variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark Lavin asked, you are probably using [the latest version of `url` tag](https://github.com/django/django/commit/eb351ac9cba2d6b2750aecb4353ba482d6dca87f)

Please

- use `{% url "contactme-post-contact-form" %}`.
- or `{% load url from future %}{% url "contactme-post-contact-form" %}` if testing server in turn fails.